# Django installed, but can't import django in python

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, python, django

I've installed Django multiple ways, via `apt-get` and `pip install`. They all say I have the most recent version of Django. Now whenever I run python in Terminal and type in import django, I receive

```
ImportError: No module named django
```

However, when I run `django-admin --version` I receive

```
1.4.3
```

I know it's installed, but why is python not finding the django module?

Comment: Did you install Python manually?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember.

Answer (score 8):

`python` is not finding `django` because it's not on its path. You can see the list of paths `python` looks for modules like this:

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

You can import `django` if you find the location it is installed, and add that location to `python`'s path, for example like this:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/path/to/django/parent/dir python
>>> import django  # should work now
```

But your real problem is that something's wrong with your `python` installation. If you have installed both `python` AND `django` using `apt-get`, then `django` should certainly be on `python`'s path without dirty hacks like above.

That said, when working with Django, your best bet is to NOT use `apt-get` but create a virtual environment using `virtualenv` (you can install `virtualenv` itself using `apt-get`), and install Django and other modules your Django site might need using `pip` within the virtual environment. That way you can have multiple Django projects side by side, with precisely the Python modules and versions it requires. It's just a few extra steps to do, but definitely worth it and will save you from much frustration in the future.

Comment: You can also add to the path directly in your code by using sys.path.append('path/to/django'), then import as normal

Comment: @NGRhodes Hardcoding paths in code is not a good idea.

Comment: can always read the path from a configuration item so its a runtime setting :)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when I was using PyCharm Community Edition for making Django projects.

For me, the following steps worked:

It turns out that python wants you to create a virtual environment, install django in that and then run the server. To do this,

#### Create a Virtual Environment

> 1) Install virtual environment using `pip install virtualenv`.
>
> 2) Navigate to the project folder and type `virtualenv env` (Here *`env`* is the name of the virtual environment.) This will create a new folder named *`env`* inside the project folder.
>
> 3) Navigate to `env/Scripts` inside your Project Folder using `cd env/Scripts`.
>
> 4) Type `activate` and press Enter. This should start the virtual environment. You can verify this as `(env)` would be prefixed to your current path.

#### Install Django

> 1) Once inside the virtual environment, head back to your project folder using `cd ../..` and type `pip install django`.
>
> 2) You can verify its installation by typing `django-admin --version`. It should display the django version number installed inside the virtual environment.

Now type `python manage.py runserver` to start the python server.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I activated the virtual environment

```
$ source bin/activate
```

after that it showed me the version of Django

There was no need of installing anything.

---

```
mamata@mamta-inspire-all:~/dodjango$ python -m django --version
/usr/bin/python: No module named django

mamata@mamta-inspire-all:~/dodjango$ django-admin --version
Command 'django-admin' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python-django-common

mamata@mamta-inspire-all:~/dodjango$ source bin/activate

(dodjango) mamata@mamta-inspire-all:~/dodjango$ ls
bin  include  lib  lib64  mamusite  pyvenv.cfg  share

(dodjango) mamata@mamta-inspire-all:~/dodjango$ django-admin --version    
2.2.5

(dodjango) mamata@mamta-inspire-all:~/dodjango$ python -m django --version
2.2.5
```

Comment: Try to edit the answer with some help of AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple python version installed into your machine. The different packages you are trying to install gets conflicted.So, the best approach is to use virtualenv..

1. Simple install virtual environment and python version
2. use virtualenv env to create virtualenvironment.
3. activate your virtualenv. using . /env_name/bin/activate
4. use pip install django==1.70 (specify version to install django)
5. pip list to list all installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem and still had it till recently in my project
vscode did not recognize my virtual environment , so when ever i try to run the project it gives me an error that vscode can not import django

the fix for this for me that i exported the libraries in my virtual environment to a fill

```
pip freeze > req.txt
```

then i created a new virtual environment with the same requirements , and it worked

note: try looking this up [python virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score -1):

I've got this problem when I renamed the project folder in PyCharm.

1. Terminal tab stopped getting into the Virtual Environment (`venv` folder). To fix that, I went to the `Settings -> Project -> Project` Interpreter and changed the folder there.
2. Django "disappeared". `django-admin --version` did not respond. To fix, I did `pip install django` within the `venv`.

It helped.