# File ignored PyCharm Pro IDE and this the correct sys.path for PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python3, paths, virtualenv, pycharm

My `PyCharm IDE` doesn't automatically create a `venv directory` so I have to manually create my own.
My `venv directory` comes up as ignored. This is normal.
A possible solution is found the comment section.
When creating a `PyCharm Project` `Django` and `virtualenv` were installed. I did *not* have to install `Django`. So now `Python3` needs a clean up.

**Update:** I've been having issues with `PyCharm IDE` for a while now and I want to be sure is the `sys.path`: 
From `PyCharm IDE terminal`:

```
>>> python3
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
    ['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/name/Projects/bye/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/name/Projects
/bye/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg', '/home/name/Projects/bye/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg']
```

Despite the directory being created I still get this result:

```
 ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
```

[image]

The ImportError is generated by line 6 of the following Python 3 code, not necessarily by the code but rather by the `from django.core.management import` on line 4.

```py
    def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Example.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Example.settings')
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'Example.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Example.wsgi.application'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the Django part see this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/250442/django-installed-but-cant-import-django-in-python

Comment: For the color explanation see this : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-status-highlights.html

Comment: I followed the import.sys and sys.path. I printed just fine, it's really long. It is that really the whole path?

Comment: Which one is it PyCharm or Main Terminal?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error message in either PyCharm or the terminal. The code in the question would not normally return this error message. Therefore the import is returning an error message because Django is either not installed correctly or else the python3.7 interpreter is unable to find the path to Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the results of `print(sys.path)`

```
$ python3
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',  
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

The results of your `print(sys.path)` show lots of user-made modifications, possibly the result of multiple unrecommended package management decisions in your Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: So what do I need to do? I only installed the software I needed. Any particular packages which are the culprit?

Comment: Clean up your Python paths, so that the python3.7 interpreter is able to find the Python packages that you have installed.

Comment: Exactly how do you clean up your python paths, without corrupting python3?

Comment: I have a backup from the early days of my Disco Django software.

Answer (score 0):

> My venv directory comes up as ignored

That's an expected behavior, you don't really need PyCharm to treat your virtual environment as a part of your project code.

> Despite the directory being created I still get this result:

Make sure the venv you created is selected as a project interpreter in **Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter** and it has Django installed.

Comment: Especially the last sentence because it corresponds to the error message in the question which I didn't get in PyCharm with my Django package which is from the default Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Some weird reason when the project is being created. That I don't open the file option in Django PyCharm will install Django. It's me from installing django from mulitple sources causing the import error.

Comment: It's when I use the import.sys and sys.path. I'm not sure that you c&p the whole thing in.